# phonegap + facebook plugin not working

Tags: facebook, plugins, cordova

I know there have been similar questions asked but none of them get addressed to the degree.

So basically I'm testing out the example index.html found in the plugin package but  when click on "login" which redirects to safari in simulator (due to lack of fb app) and fb app in my iphone, it open up the diag to "allow" my app but after that it never returns to my app..

I do have facebook id to replace the one in the index.html and the setup of plugin works: it compiles and runs.

When I go back to my app myself to click on the button to populate my friends list, it says:

{"message", "An active token is required to query...}

**Update: I just fixed the problem myself.** It's actually due to my setup (it compiles but it won't work):

In YourApp-info.plist, the URL should be

> fb#appID

But in example index.html, it should be

> #appID

(without the fb prefix)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint Im not sure about. what is the id you entered for fb[APP_ID] have you entered fbfb (twice)

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
    <string>[SCHEME_ID]</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fb[APP_ID]</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</array>
```